# Apache Django Internal Server Error (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu-18.04, mod-wsgi, wagtail

I have a Django wagtail application. I can run it in debug and I can run it on a django server but if I try to run it on my Ubuntu 18.04 server using Apache2 WSGI I get "Internal Server Error". Apache log:

```
[Mon Jan 18 23:29:23.673557 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 92324:tid 140613127453760] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x7fe301c1fc10>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in __del__
NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fe301b95040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/wow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fe301b95040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/wow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
Exception ignored in: <function Local.__del__ at 0x7fe301b95040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/wow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/local.py", line 96, in __del__
NameError: name 'TypeError' is not defined
[Mon Jan 18 23:29:24.194636 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 92749:tid 139932982541376] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 18 23:29:24.194764 2021] [core:notice] [pid 92749:tid 139932982541376] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 18 23:29:31.468972 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 92750:tid 139932932445952] WSGI without exception
```

my wsgi file:

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "americanss.settings.production")

application = get_wsgi_application()

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    print('WSGI without exception')
except Exception:
    print('handing WSGI exception')
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

from what I have found, the exceptions raised happen and nobody seems to know why but most of the time it doesn't stop the app from running. In my case I get a 500 error and I can't tell if that is related to the traceback because no one else reports a 500 with these errors.

apactctl -M:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 143.110.226.199. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
```